# Magento admin panel SKU on products sort order causes fatal error

Tags: database, magento, admin, magento-1.6

On Magento 1.6 with 4000+ products. Over half have the following error when trying to sort by SKU:

- in Admin Product Grid
- also: in Admin Product Grid searching for some products by sku yields no result (but they are in the grid and have a numeric sku set)

Frontend,  the products look and work fine, but cannot be found by searching the sku.

Having inspected the database a bit, it seems that the products that are not working have an entry missing in:

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

If I edit a product, change the sku, save, then re-edit and restore the original sku its all back to normal and working again. dont want to do that 2500+ times. Do you think I can programatically rebuild the missing sku entries in catalog_product_entity_varchar ? is there a better route?

Looking in the category_product_flat tables, the sku field for the broken products is set to null. Why would the SKU data not carry over from the main catalog_product_entity table?

Comment: What do you have in your system.log and exception.log?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you imported the products and forgot to set the right sku field.
You could just fetch the collection via:

```
$count=0;
foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() as $_product){
  $count++;
  $_product->setSku("SKU".$count);
  $_product->save();

}
```

Of course you can set the sku to something that makes more sense...

Comment: it was actually  a plugin that imported things. We have fixed the symptoms by using a script but would like to understand the cause better! Pretty sure it is the result of the third party import however, and we won't revisit that.

Comment: as i told you, its a faulty import, maybe because of a badly named column header. If you used the above hint or did something similar...the topic is closed - from my opinion.

Comment: i upvoted your answer but it wasnt so much to helping fix the db player problem. Happy to have question closed as it's a one-off issue most likely , since plugin derived. thanks